# systemctl: command not found on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, mongodb, linux-headers

when I tried to install RocketChat in Ubuntu 16.04

In Command Prompt I enter.

```
systemctl enable mongod
```

After That I got The issue.

```
systemctl: command not found
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Try this on terminal: `dpkg-query -S /bin/systemctl `.

Comment: I tried this and i got "dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /bin/systemctl."

Comment: @VigneshRamamoorthy:
What does this command give you `whereis systemctl`?

Comment: I tried to install systemd package,i got the error "Package systemd is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source" E: Package 'systemd' has no installation candidate

Comment: whereis systemctl command gives "systemctl:"@saurav kumar

Comment: Are you sure you are using Ubuntu 16.04? Please update your post with output of `cat /etc/os-release` and `ls -al $(which init)`.

Comment: Sorry my version is 12.04.5 LTS. NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="12.04.5 LTS, Precise Pangolin"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)"
VERSION_ID="12.04"
How To install RocketChat in ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS, Precise Pangolin..Have any tutorial guide?

Answer (score 99):

1. First you need to check if **systemd** package is installed - `sudo dpkg -l | grep systemd`.
2. If not then install it by hands `sudo apt-get install systemd`. But if it does it might be damaged, so you may try to reinstall it `sudo apt-get install --reinstall systemd`.
3. If the package is installed, even after reinstallation it does not work, list the full path of the files inside this package `sudo dpkg -L systemd`. Maybe binary files are located in a directory that is not included into **$PATH** variable.

Comment: I tried to install systemd package,i got the error "Package systemd is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source"     E: Package 'systemd' has no installation candidate

Comment: What is the output of `sudo apt-cache search systemd`?

Comment: This is output of sudo apt-cache search systemd "live-config-systemd - Debian Live - System Configuration Scripts (systemd backend)
nagios-plugins-contrib - Plugins for nagios compatible monitoring systems"

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` after the system was installed? I think you have some problem with your repositories.

Comment: Please fix your Answer: `apt-get install --reinstall systemd`

Comment: Just reinstall the package `apt-get install --reinstall systemd` and see if any of the paths from `dpkg -L systemd` is in you `echo $PATH`.